# How to automatically download files from internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to download a file from the internet (its a execl file) so I want to use VBA to automate the entire process. I have the address of the file but I just want to download it and then save it. The other thing is that it can only be opened in internet explorer the file cannot be opened in chrome or firefox.

Comment: Is the [URLDownloadToFile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775123) not working for you?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `URLDownloadToFile` API function

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
        Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
        Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
#End If
    Sub Demo()
         URLDownloadToFile 0, _
        "http://www.example.com/myworkbook.xlsx", _
        "C:\users\me\documents\myworkbook.xlsx", 0, 0
    End Sub
```

Comment: To be thorough, you might want to include the ptrsafe ×64 version with a compiler directive.